DJI F450 Drone Kit Equivalent
I wanted to buy the DJI F450 Drone Kit, however as it is no longer produced, I want to buy an equivalent. Does anyone know any Pre-soldered drone kit like the DJI F450 that can lift a camera, jetson nano, claw, and at least one more lipo battery?
I was considering the HAWK'S WORK F450 pre-soldered Drone kit, but I didn't really trust it. There are barely any reviews or videos of people building it. Would this drone properly suit my needs, or does anyone know any reliable alternatives?
